# How do I change the font family of a reactjs button component?

Tags: css, reactjs, fonts

I can't for the life of me figure out how to change the font family of the text wrapped in a reactjs button component. I've tried class overrides, but it always renders as Times New Roman. I've also tried wrapping the text in a Typography component and applying class overrides but that didn't work either.

Here is my button component:

```
<Button
  variant="contained"
  className={classes.sideBarButtons}
  fullWidth
>
Some Text
</Button>
```

Here is my class override using makeStyles:

```
  sideBarButtons: {
    height: "25%",
    background: "#FF0000",
    borderRadius: 0,
    color: "white",
    paddingTop: "2em",
    paddingBottom: "2em",
    fontFamily: 'Roboto',
  },
```

Comment: You tried using the tag "important" to override existing classes, for example: fontFamily: 'Roboto !important',

Comment: Where is the Button component coming from?

Comment: @JoshBirdwell its coming from the material-ui/core npm package. [link](https://material-ui.com/components/buttons/)

Answer (score 1):

Material ui uses inline styles, so to override it try:

```
<Button style={{ fontFamily: 'Roboto' }} label='Styled button' />
```

or

```
<Button labelStyle={{ fontFamily: 'Roboto' }} label='Styled button' />
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Than import it inside `App.js`

`import 'styles/font.css'`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is another css rule with high priority in your stylesheet file that is styling your button with **Times New Roman**. Using a browser, inspect your button element to see which css rule is setting the Times New Roman font and fix it.

It is important to remark that Button component of **MATERIAL-UI** is set by default its font-family with Roboto

Answer (score 0):

In button.js file:

```
import './button.css';

const Button = ({ children }) => (
    <button>{ children }</button>
);
```

And then in button.css file:

```
button {
   font-family: "Roboto"
}
```

- { children } is the text in between the  tags. So in the code above, { children } is passed in from the file that is using your custom button.

For example, if you are using ur custom button in SignIn.js:

```
import Button from './button';

<div>
     // "Sign In" is the { children }
     <Button type="submit">Sign In</Button>
</div>
```